# How can I fix this error? ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, valueerror, mediapipe, cvzone

```
import cv2 as cv
import csv
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import cvzone as cvz

# Declaring the cap variable to start Camera activity

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)

detector = HandDetector(minTrackCon=0.8)  


# Class to access the elements of Que.csv file via indexing

class Questions:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.question = data[0]
        self.choice1 = data[1]
        self.choice2 = data[2]
        self.choice3 = data[3]
        self.choice4 = data[4]
        self.answer = int(data[5])
        self.userAnswer = None

# importing CSV file

getFile = 'Que.csv'
with open(getFile, newline='\n') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    datafile = list(reader)[1:]

# Creating Object for Each

mcqList = []
for que in datafile:
    mcqList.append(Questions(que))

print(len(mcqList))

queNumber = 0
queTotal = len(datafile)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # To Flip the camera view to the original side
    hands, frame = detector.findHands(frame, flipType=True)
    mcq = mcqList[0]

    frame, box = cvz.putTextRect(frame, mcq.question, [50, 50], 2, 2, offset=15, border=4)
    frame, box1 = cvz.putTextRect(frame, mcq.choice1, [50, 115], 1, 2, offset=15, border=4)
    frame, box2 = cvz.putTextRect(frame, mcq.choice2, [150, 115], 1, 2, offset=15, border=4)
    frame, box3 = cvz.putTextRect(frame, mcq.choice3, [50, 165], 1, 2, offset=15, border=4)
    frame, box4 = cvz.putTextRect(frame, mcq.choice4, [150, 165], 1, 2, offset=15, border=4)

    # Checking for a Hand
    if hands:
        lmList = hands[0]['lmList']
        length, info, frame = detector.findDistance(lmList[8],lmList[12],frame)
        print(length)

    cv.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried to solve this using different methods but the error still persists. The error message is shown below...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\CODE\.vscode\OpenCV\main.py", line 57, in <module>
    length, info = detector.findDistance(lmList[0],lmList[12])
  File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cvzone\HandTrackingModule.py", line 143, in findDistance
    x1, y1 = p1
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I have tried using different versions of mediapipe as well but still the issue exists....

**I'm Expecting the code to detect the distance between my two finger's**

For example in the above code I have selected my index finger tip that is lmList[8] and my middle finger tip that is lmList[12] and now i want the code to tell me the distance between both of them.

Comment: Where is the documentation of `findDistance`? You are passing incorrect arguments to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [cvzone HandTrackingModule module source code](https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone/blob/master/cvzone/HandTrackingModule.py), each `lmList` element contains three values: `px`, `py`, and `pz`. So, you should pass the first two elements instead of all three elements:

```
...
length, info = detector.findDistance(lmList[0][:2],lmList[12][:2])
...
```

To see an example within the library itself, you can refer to [HandTrackingModule.py#L189](https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone/blob/a6d0d6d4219956fde1f3f1af66a12434500130ba/cvzone/HandTrackingModule.py#L189).

Comment: Thank you Sir for your valuable information. It had helped me to solve my error.